# How to organize postgresql databases in pgadmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-13

I'm working with postgresql on my local machine with Windows 10, in pgadmin4 I can create new Server Groups and new Servers, if I create 2 new server groups and select localhost for the host, I get all the databases I've created on my computer.

Is there any way to split all the databases I create on my local machine into separate groups?

Answer (score 0):

On the server "Properties..." dialog on the "Advanced" tab, there is a "DB restriction" field that lets you enter the databases which will be visible from that server.

You can have different server entries in different groups which connect to the same instance, but which differ in their "DB restriction" field.